# Not able to view open files from Windows Computer Management

Tags: windows, permissions, readynas

We have two Netgear ReadyNAS 4312 devices on different subnets. Using the Windows Computer Management MMC, I can view the open files on one but not the other. Both devices appear to have the same configuration and permissions set.
When trying to view the open files on device 2, I get the following message: "You do not have permissions to see the list of files opened by Windows clients".
I'm logged into a Windows machine using a domain admin acount and both NAS boxes have the domain admins group set on the shares.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which subnet is the computer on? Does connecting from a computer on a different subnet make a difference?

Comment: The computer I'm using is on the same subnet.

Comment: You mentioned there are two subnets in your setup. Saying your computer is on the "same subnet" doesn't answer the question. Please rewrite the question being much clearer on the configuration of your network and the devices on it and the specific settings you have tested.